# Oracle Virtualbox CentOS Guest Additions failed to download

Tags: virtualbox, centos, guest-additions

I have host Ubuntu 19.04, and have Oracle Virtualbox 6.0.6. 
I have successfully installed Guest Additions on Oracle Linux guest, 
But on CentOS 7.6 guest, it doesn't even wanna download it

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can download it manually and use the ISO as virtual CDROM.
https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.6/ the file name is VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.6.iso

It's a singe ISO for all systems currently supported.